# Limit the number of rows of 1D associative arrays written in to a csv file in PHP

Tags: php, csv, associative-array, export-to-csv, fputcsv

I have a large number of one dimensional arrays stored in memory cache and I want to write them to a CSV files, the arrays come one by one through the use of a queue. But I want to "limit each csv file to about 100 rows" and then write the remaining arrays into newer files and so on.
I would highly appreciate any help in this.
I used this function to pass arrays into a csv but I don't know how to limit the number of rows to 100 and then open new files and write to them.
The messages passed in the queue are keys named as SO1,SO2, SO3 n so on with the last message being passed as "LAST". And based on the keys , the arrays associated with the keys are read in from memcache and have to be written into csv files. The messages reach one after another via rabitmq queue from a preceeding module.
// Assuming $S01 is an array fetched from memcache based on the key say S01 received via a queue.
    $SO1 = array('Name'=> 'Ubaid', 'Age'=>'24', 'Gender'=>'Male','Lunch'=>'Yes', 'Total'=> '1000');

```
$row_count= 0;
$csv_file_count= 1;


while($msg != "LAST" ){  // As long as msg recieved is not LAST
$csv = fopen("file_". $csv_file_count.".csv", "w");
    fputcsv($csv, array_keys($SO));
    while($msg != "LAST" && $row_count<100){                    
        fputcsv($csv, $SO);         // Write toCSV
        $row_count++;
    }
    $row_count=0;                                   
    $csv_file_count++;                                              
    fclose($csv);
```

Comment: Keep a counter, if counter >= 100, close file, open new file, reset counter...!?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a counter like this.

```
$row_count = 0;
$csv_file_count = 1;


while (!$q->isEmpty()){            // as long as the queue is not empty
    $csv = fopen("file_".$csv_file_count.".csv", "w");   // open "file_n.csv" n file number
    fputcsv($csv,explode(',',"col1,col2,col3,col4"));    // Your custom headers
    while (!$q->isEmpty() && $row_count < 100){          // so while queue is not empty and the counter didnt reach 100
        fputcsv($csv, explode(',',$q->pop()));       // write to file. Explode by , or space or whatever your data looks like
        $row_count++;                  // increment row counter
    }
    $row_count = 0;            // when that is not true anymore, reset row counter
    $csv_file_count++;         // increment file counter
    $csv.close()           // close file
}  // repeats untill queue is empty
```

Updated to use fputcsv()

If you want another seperator in your csv file you can do like this:

```
fputcsv($csv, explode(',',explode(',',$q->pop()),";"); // (;) for example. Default is comma (,)
```

You can also specify a field enclosure

```
fputcsv($csv, explode(',',explode(',',$q->pop()),",","'"); // (') for example. Default is double quote (")
```

fputcsv() takes 2 required parameters and 2 optional

From [php.net fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

```
int fputcsv ( resource $handle , array $fields [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape_char = "\" ]]] )
```

Fields shall be an array, therefore

```
explode(',',$q->pop())
```

as the 2nd parameter

Comment: Highly Appreciated @EL3PHANTEN. What adds to it though is that I am required to put the first row of every csv file to be certain headers. Where can I place those in the code if i need to hardcode them? And I want to use fputcsv.

Comment: @UbaidShowkat I have updated the answer to use fputcsv, and added custom headers

Comment: @UbaidShowkat did this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks again El3phaten. It did help a great deal but may i ask the necessity of using POP() here?

Comment: @UbaidShowkat you say you have them in a que. So if you pop elements out of it, it is easy to check if the que is empty

Comment: @El3phaten: They are coming to me via rabbitMQ queue. Instead of using the expression of checking whether the queue is empty or not I have used a condition like :` while ($msg=='LAST')` coz as soon as I receive a message as "LAST" in the queue I have to stop writing to CSV. If in case i want to hard code some values in the CSV and they should be written in every row what approach should I use? These values will be same for every row.

Comment: @UbaidShowkat can you show me one line? Or update the question with an example of one line from the que?

Comment: @EL3PHATEN: please refer to my updated question and code. I am thinking of adding those values to the incoming arrays which i have to hardcode into the csv and then put that updated array into the function.